# Can't access Jenkins running on a Raspberry Pi using port 8080

Tags: networking, jenkins, raspberry-pi, port, raspbian

I'm trying to access my jenkins service running on port 8080 through my local network, but for some reason it is not allowing me to connect. I can remote into the pi and launch a web browser and type in localhost:8080 and it works fine.

This is a bare bones installation of raspbian and I have not installed a firewall on it, so not sure why I would not be able to access jenkins on my local network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is true,

> I can remote into the pi and launch a web browser and type in localhost:8080 and it seems to work fine.

you can focus on firewall/iptables/routing/ip configuration issues, so let's go ahead with those.

Let's say your Raspberry Pi has ip `192.168.0.10/24` and you are accessing from a device on the same network.

**Firewall**

You said it is dissabled, so we can forget about it.

**Iptables**

Check what rules you have

`iptables -L`

flush all of them for testing in case there's any

`iptables -F`

**Routing**

You are on the same network, so there shouldn't be problems here.

**Ip Configuration**

`ping 192.168.0.10`

Not working? Then check your configuration

```
route -n
ifconfig
```

Everything as it should? `ping` again while you execute

`tcpdump -i eth0 -n              #(or use whireshark if possible)`

on both machines. You will be able to see there what's going on. What you can see there:

- Request is not being sent => `most lickely missconfiguration on source`
- Request is being sent and answer not => `most lickely missconfiguration on dest`
- Both are being sent, but answer is not recieved => `missconfiguration of firewall on source or routing problem (probably not your case)`

---

If everything above works and is as it should, you then have to focus on the service running on the Pi. Is it listenning on every IP and accepting connections from anywhere (or at least your network)?

If not, change your configuration and you should be good and running.

Comment: This was extremley detailed and helpful.. After running through the steps you outlined I realized it was an issue with Jenkins not accepting connections from other computers on the network. There was a property in the /etc/default/jenkins file called HTTP_HOST and I changed tthat from 127.0.0.1 to 198.162.1.0/24 and that seemed to make it available to all the computers on my network.